# TypeError: Error #1006: playContent is not a function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, namespaces

I have a class that holds an object from another class. When I want to call some function from this class, I get the above error... See code to get a better idea!

MainMenu.as

```
package portfolioSource  {      
    public class MainMenu extends MovieClip {

        private var movieContainer:MoviePlayerContainer;

        public function MainMenu() {

            movieContainer = new MoviePlayerContainer();
            this.addChild(movieContainer);

        }

        function ef_btnTheme1CLICK(event:Event){

            movieContainer.playContent(1);//It breaks here

        }           
    }       
}
```

and MoviePlayerContainer.as

```
package portfolioSource  {    
    public class MoviePlayerContainer extends MovieClip {   

        public function playContent(_parameter:Number){

            trace("I do not work");

        }
    }

}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Not one of the functions in the movieContainer object works. I get the same error every time. The constructor (omitted here) does not get executed, but it generates no error...

When I remove the package part and leave it default like :

```
package {
    public class someClass{
    }
}
```

Then it works. So I am really confused now.

Thanks!

Comment: Are You extending MovieClip from library ? If yes , thats because MoviePlayerContainer have wrong path to Your class , close to class alias label is button that can chack connection to external .as file . Click it and check linkage

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have 2 classes being defined with the same name on different packages. You should remove or rename one of them.

I'm unaware if Flash supports this, but see if this works: `private var movieContainer : portfolioSource.MoviePlayerContainer;`

Comment: I indeed have 2 classes with the same name. But like you said, they are in different packages. Shouldn't the packages part fix this? As I understand it that's what packages are for!

I am trying to load an external swf into my main swf. This external swf uses classes that are named the same as the main swf, and this is breaking everything.

I was hoping packages might fix it. Oh well.

Comment: The problem is that the default (empty) package is always included, and also all classes from the same package are included, so you have 2 classes with the same name being included and the compiler doesn't know what to do.

Comment: I understand that. I then changed my base swf's package to the one above (portfolioSource), and left the loaded swf's package default. This gave me the error as described above.

Comment: Have your loaded swf package be swfdescription.portfolioSource and your main package be main.portfolioSource, that way they won't get mixed around.